# PersistenceException on cascade if OneToMany related entity is detached

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

given this simple example (https://github.com/lelmarir/jpa-cascade-bug-test):

```
runInTransaction(em, () -> {
   Parent p = em.find(Parent.class, id);
   Child firstChild = p.getChilds().get(0);

   em.detach(firstChild);
   em.flush();
});
```

it will fail with this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.Child
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    at com.example.App.lambda$1(App.java:47)
    at com.example.App.runInTransaction(App.java:62)
    at com.example.App.main(App.java:40)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.Child
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
    ... 4 more
```

should i report this as an Hibernate bug or is it an expected behaviour?

Comment: Why are you calling detach?

Comment: This is just an example, but in my actual application I'm using em.detach(em.getReference(...)) to get a proxy reference. I'm detaching the proxy to get an error if someone tries to access a property (I'm just interested in the id). But if the entity is present in the persistenceContext it gets returned instead of the proxy, causing this problem. Anyway, sometime I need to detach some entities to be sure they don't get persisted if modified in transaction without an explicit merge.

Answer (score 0):

> is it an expected behaviour?

Yes.

Let me quote two excerpts from the [JPA Specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) that apply here:

The first one:

> The state of persistent entities is **synchronized** to the database **at transaction commit**. (...) If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database. (...) For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been
>   annotated with the cascade element value **cascade=PERSIST** or cascade=ALL, the **persist operation is applied to Y**

The second one:

> The semantics of the persist operation, applied to an entity X are as follows:
>   (...)
>   If X is **a detached object**, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the persist
>   operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException or **another PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time**.

(emphasis mine)

I noticed a lot of people are confused by this behaviour, actually expecting JPA flush to behave as though `merge()` was called on the parent entity. **But**, since the parent entity is already managed, there's nothing to *merge* at that point.

Comment: Right, I get this, but I feel it strange that the transaction is failing because a cascading child of the parent entity is detached. Any modification to the parent should be persisted and any detached child just being ignored. Isn't it?

Comment: Ahh now I think I see where you're coming from. You want to say 'ignore all the changes for this entity when flushing the transaction'. Such a feature would be unintuitive to the extreme, because what the application sees is not what ultimately gets saved in the DB

Comment: What you can do, though, is you can use `EntityManager.refresh()` on entities you want to prevent from modification. The entities will simply return to their original state, with any modifications reverted. This way, the state the application sees and the state that gets saved will now be in sync